# XSD schema: How to specify the number of digits in a value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

i want to limit the number of digits allowed in an element to 6:

```
<AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>999999</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>000000</AccountNumber>
```

The field format specification is 6-digit, zero-padded, numeric.

[i read that i might want to use](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) the `totalDigits` restriction, based on:

> `totalDigits`  Specifies the exact number of digits allowed. Must be greater than zero

So i have the simple type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AccountNumber">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:totalDigits value="6"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And while it catches invalid numbers, such as:

```
<AccountNumber>1234567</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>0000000</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
```

it doesn't catch invalid numbers:

```
<AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>01234</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>00123</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>00012</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>00001</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>00000</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>0000</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>000</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>00</AccountNumber>
<AccountNumber>0</AccountNumber>
```

What is a suggested restriction to specify the exact number of digits allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`xs:pattern`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) and provide a regular expression to limit it to a number.

```
<xs:simpleType name="AccountNumber">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{6}"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: i was about to say, *"You can use a pattern with an `xs:int`? Well how about that."*

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I was a little surprised too. I learned something answering this. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [xs:minInclusive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dc-minInclusive) and [xs:maxInclusive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dc-maxInclusive).

Comment: ... takes SO a while to notify that other answers have been posted

Comment: I believe those limit by value not by number of digits. As in if minInclusive is 7 it means the value 7, not 7 digits.

Comment: @Jeff - would you believe that `minInclusive` of 1000000 is seven digits? And that `maxExclusive` of 9999999 is also seven digits?

Comment: @Anon: It's a bit of a dodgy way to enforce the length. Nice attitude though. ;)

Comment: @Jeff - I don't think it's dodgy, as long as the type is `xs:int`. Rereading the question however, the OP wants to preserve leading zeroes, which says to me that the type should really be `xs:string`.

Comment: @Anon: We're entitled to our opinions, but I very strongly feel that this is a hack rather than  the best way to achieve the goal. Especially since the right way is so easy.

Comment: @Jeff - :shrug: hacks are where you find them. For me, constraining *integer values* by anything other than a *numeric limit* is a hack. *String* values, on the other hand, are appropriately constrained by regexes. My point is that the OP's data type is the issue.

Comment: @Anon: I clearly disagree. The data type is exactly right if they want these values to be interpreted as integers and enforcing a length with a pattern seems right in that situation. Enforcing length by constraining min and max values is a workaround. I don't believe the OP has got their data type wrong here, the data type just needs additional constraints to fit the use-case and these are provided by using a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way

```
    <xs:element name="prodid">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```