# SoapUI not recognizing valid regex

Tags: regex, xsd, wsdl, soapui

If I pass a value such as `123456789`, **SOAP UI** throws a validation error.
    Any idea what is the correct regex for checking an integer pattern in SOAP UI?

Repeating the pattern `[0-9] 9` times works though but `[0-9]{9}` doesn't.

I am using something like the snippet below in my *xsd* file being referred to by my *wsdl*

```
<simpleType name="ZipCode">
            <restriction base="integer">
              <pattern value="^\d{9}$"/> 
             </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: You seem to need `<pattern value="[0-9]{9}"/>`, without `^` and `$`. XSD regex supports limiting quantifiers, so `{9}` should work.

Comment: I tried even this didn't help.

Comment: Ok, I remember there are several flavors of XSD regex, so probably you are using the "less powerful" one. If `{9}` does not work, just repeat the `[0-9]` as many times as you need.

Comment: Yes that seems the only way to get this working :(

Comment: @Twisha, please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228607/xsd-schema-how-to-specify-the-number-of-digits-in-a-value) is relevant?